# Return SQL Query result in JSON Format in Azure Synapse

Tags: json, sql-server, azure-synapse

I want my SQL query result in JSON Format in Azure Synapse. I can use 'FOR JSON AUTO' in Azure SQL Database but while running it in Azure Synapse it gives an error. Is there any alternate way in Synapse to return query result in JSON Format?

Comment: As you've discovered, the feature is not yet supported in Synapse. You can upvote it here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-azure-synapse-analytics/suggestions/42520126-support-for-for-json-auto-and-for-json-path-in-azu